# interact with the sample CorDappVia the interactive shell

Tags: corda

When i checked the output  ：run vaultQuery contractStateType: com.example.state.IOUState
it show :
Could not parse as a command: Cannot construct instance of `java.lang.Class`, problem: com.example.state.IOUState
at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1]

Answer (score 0):

I typed net.corda.samples.example.states.IOUState and it worked.
You see the package name in ExampleFlow.kt.

Comment: hey, it would be great to add a better explanation for the OP to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Nice @shok1122.

Paste & run:  run vaultTrack contractStateType: net.corda.samples.example.states.IOUState